# What is the driving force of Bartoli indole synthesis?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, aromatic-compounds, molecular-orbital-theory, grignard-reagent

[image]
The Bartoli indole synthesis mechanism begins with a series of attacks on the nitroarene regent by the Grignard reagents. But the atom $\ce{O}$ in $\ce{-NO2}$ should be negative, and Grignard reagent is also be negative, they should repel each other. So, why the first step happens?

I calculate the ESP and the LUMO of nitrobenzene by NBO.

[image: ESP]

[image: LUMO(33)]

If it is because HOMO(Grignard)-LUMO(nitrobenzene) is bigger than their electrostatic repulsion, why aromatic nitro compounds perform $\ce{S_{N}Ar}$ on benzene ring instead of $\ce{-NO2}$?

Comment: *"why aromatic nitro compounds perform SNAr on benzene ring instead of −NO2"* — I feel like this is the sort of thing that is traditionally explained with so-called HSAB theory, although there is a strong argument that HSAB theory is completely wrong, and should be replaced with transition state theory / Marcus theory which may be relevant here. https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/anie.201007100 I wonder if it's enough to model the starting material; you may need to study the entire reaction (and also consider the potential reversibility of competing pathways).

Comment: Where did you find this mechanism? It's overly elaborate and, likely, simply wrong.

Comment: OK, I found the picture is from Commons - better link directly. Ref. for the mechanism seems to be https://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlelanding/1991/P2/p29910000657

Comment: @orthocresol, Thanks. According to HSAB, hard-hard preference  is electrostatic stabilization, soft-soft preference is HOMO-LUMO interactions, the LUMO is mainly on $\ce{−NO2}$. The $\pi$ orbital of $\ce{−NO2}$ may be harder than benzene ring, and Grignard reagent is kind of hard soft, so hard-hard should be on $\ce{−NO2}$? Then why on atom $\ce{O}$ instead of $\ce{N}$?